# Is there any fast way to find assembler source code?

Tags: assembly, grep, reverse-engineering

I am trying to find dietlibc source code for basic functions like printf, puts, etc. Currently using grep {command_name} -r -A20 in the folder where they should be, but it seems really exhausting. Is there any faster way?

Another known way is to reverse object files for each function, but i think it will take more time.

Comment: What did the author say when you contacted them?

Comment: Removed irrelevant C tag

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem? Seems like the files are well organized and well named. If I want to find the ARM code for `strcpy()`, it's in [`.../arm/strcpy.S`](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/arm/strcpy.S). Loading the files into an IDE would probably help.

Comment: @Caleb It is a standard C library, builded from scratch for embedded devices. I've already found folder with *.S files, but for the most basic functions such as printf() there are only .c files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've already found folder with *.S files, but for the most basic functions such as printf() there are only .c files

Many functions *are* written in C, and they're written in terms of other C functions and/or assembly language functions. So `printf()` (in `.../libstdio/printf.c`), for example, uses `vprintf()`, which uses `__v_printf()` (in `.../lib/__v_printf.c`), which uses `strcpy()` and `strlen()` etc., which have ARM implementations in `.../arm`. Some functions are implemented both in C and assembly, probably because assembly provides a performance boost on some architectures but not others (or possibly because nobody has gotten around to writing assembly versions for some architectures).

So, if you're looking for `printf.S`, you're probably not going to find it for any architecture because it's a relatively high level function that calls other functions. That means that you can port dietlibc to a new architecture without having to write assembly versions of every function in the library; you only have to implement a small set of essential routines. Read the [PORTING](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/PORTING) file to get an idea of what has to be done to port to a new architecture, and that'll help you understand what those core routines are. Or, just look in several of the architecture-specific directories and see what they implement.

Comment: and when you compile it the resulting asm and/or machine code can vary from compiler to compiler, version and settings.  The C is the source, not any asm.  As well as printf being one of the most massive functions in a C library when you account for all the support code (other functions) required plus a lot of the compiler library as well.